Bishop's approximation theorem
I am trying to study the generalization that Axler made to Cuckovic work on the commutants of $T_{z^n}$ (Toeplitz operator with symbol $z^n$) on $L^{2}(\mathbb{D},dA)$, in the resource I am using, the following statement is given as a lemma used in the proof of the main theorem
Bishop's Approximation Theorem. Let $\psi$ be a non-constant bounded analytic function on $\Omega$, then the norm closed subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(\Omega,dA)$ generated by $\overline{\psi}$ and bounded analytic functions on $\Omega$, contains $C(\overline{\Omega})$
Where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain
Can someone help me understand what this theorem is stating and clarify the meaning of it, to make my question more precise  I need references that discuss the definition of a generated subalgebra by a set.

Maybe I’m a bit unfamiliar with the field but I don’t understand a lot of the notation. Is $\Omega$ assumed to be a Euclidean domain? Is $\overline{\psi}$ the function extended to the boundary by the trace? Is the norm closed subalgebra here the generated subalgebra closed under strong limits?

$\Omega$ is  what is called a Widom domain for example a  finitely connected domain is one , but for our intents and purposes lets think of omega as stated in Axlers papers which is a  bounded open domain in the complex plane, the extension of  $\overline{\psi}$ is a technicality and what we want from it here is that it's possible, now as for the last point thats really where my question lies, the term generated subalgebra has no clear definition and it is where my question lies

This looks a lot like Bishop's generalisation of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Maybe reference's there can help?

As for the definition of a generated subalgebra by a set $S$,
it is the smallest algebra containing that set,
which is the intersection of all subalgebras containing $S$.
A possible reference is Takesaki's Theory of Operator Algebras I, p. 18. Although it only says that "It is clear" that this intersection of all subalgebras containing $S$ is the smallest subalgebra containing $S$,
it is not very difficult to show.
(Takesaki actually considers this for $C^*$-subalgebras.)
Let $B$ be the norm closed subalgebra of $L^\infty(\Omega,dA)$
generatd by $\overline{\psi}$ and bounded analytic functions on $\Omega$.
The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem (of which Bishop's can be seen as a generalisation)
tells you that $B$ equals $C(\Omega)$.
If $\overline{\Omega}$ is some extension of $\Omega$,
then regarding the algebra $C(\overline{\Omega})$
perhaps you do want to use Bishop's Theorem,
considering that it looks at restrictions of functions,
but I'm only guessing here.
